# Convert sklearn random forest model into raw python code

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

If I have a sklearn random forest model like the one below, how would I convert the tree to raw Python code? I.e. rather than call the predict() function for the classifier, I want the tree in raw code so I can use it in an embedded application. I can generate C++ code like this using MicroMLgen, but I need Python.

```
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from os.path import basename
# Import chosen classifier function
# (for alternatives see https://github.com/eloquentarduino/micromlgen)
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
# For exporting model to Arduino C code
from micromlgen import port

# Load training dataset from csv files 
def load_features(folder):
    dataset = None
    classmap = {}
    for class_idx, filename in enumerate(glob('%s/*.csv' % folder)):
        class_name = basename(filename)[:-4]
        classmap[class_idx] = class_name
        samples = np.loadtxt(filename, dtype=float, delimiter=',')
        labels = np.ones((len(samples), 1)) * class_idx
        samples = np.hstack((samples, labels))
        dataset = samples if dataset is None else np.vstack((dataset, samples))
    return dataset, classmap

# Load data, apply classifier, output as Arduino format 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load training data from the specified subfolder
    features, classmap = load_features('training_data')
    # Create classifier function from feature set
    X, y = features[:, :-1], features[:, -1]
    classifier = RandomForestClassifier(20, max_depth=10).fit(X, y)
    # Use MicroMLgen to port classifier to Arduino C-code
    c_code = port(classifier, classmap=classmap)
    # Show generated code
    print(c_code)
```

The output should look someting like this (except in Python)....

```
                int predict(float *x) {
                    uint8_t votes[26] = { 0 };
                    // tree #1
                    if (x[2] <= 25.0) {
                        if (x[1] <= 39.0) {
                            if (x[0] <= 268.0) {
                                votes[4] += 1;
                            }

                            else {
                                votes[19] += 1;
                            }
                        }

                        else {
                            if (x[0] <= 302.0) {
                                if (x[0] <= 115.0) {
                                    if (x[0] <= 86.0) {
etc etc...
```